# Function is not a function even if it is being written in app.js and controller.js

Tags: angularjs

Thanks to some great experts who helped me with below code, I could move on to the next step.

The next step is,  problem. Of course, I have searched the online to find some answers, but I guess I missed it or didn't fully understand it.

I am getting

> "ProjectService.getProjects is not a function"

from Controller.js below. App.js has getProjects() as a function, but it is saying that it is not a function in controller.js.

[Controller.js]

```
function ProjectCtrl($scope, $http, ProjectService, $timeout, $state, $stateParams) {
...
$scope.projects =  ProjectService.getProjects();
...
};
```

[app.js]

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myProject', []);
app.service('ProjectService', function($http) {
    $http.get("projects_read.php", {})
        .then(function(response){
            var pjts = response.data;
            this.getProjects = function() { //ERROR occurs
                return pjts;  
            };

            this.getProject = function(id) {
                for (var i = 0; i < pjts.length; i++) {
                    if (pjts[i].id === id) {
                        return pjts[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            console.log(pjts);
        }.bind(this));
    })
})();
```

Other documents say that it could be some misplacement of the names of orders, etc. I think I have put the function call in a right place, but it does not work.

Hope I am not asking anything time-wasting. Even if it could be so, it is still important to me and probably too for some beginners. :)

Please advise me why I am getting this FUNCTION IS NOT A FUNCTION issue when it is being written in the app.js code.

[Reference Link] http://plnkr.co/edit/VJxlqguJZGrIutAFLCNc?p=preview

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: There are several issues with this. (1) your function is in the wrong scope in your service (2) it's inside of an asynchronous function `$http` (3) you are trying to return a value, whereas you should be returning a promise with a value from `$http.get`

Comment: Could you provide your `controller` code also.

Comment: @Evans, the controller.js code is up there. I left all the trivial stuff out.

Comment: @Aleksey, first of all, thank you for your comment. I moved the function out of the $http.get and when I put a static data instead of bring data from the server, it worked! but, how can I load the data from the PHP and server?

Comment: @JamesD. I better example of what you want to do could help. What do you mean by load, and what kind of data is expected?